# Calculate Area of Discrete Regions in a Raster Image Using R

Tags: r, spatstat, r-maptools, r-ppp

I have a raster image (20231031_110019.png, although it could be any format, jpg, png, bmp) and would like to individually [image]calculate the areas of discrete regions (I will call them 'islands' although they are actually areas of fungal growth on a petri dish) in this raster.

I am trying to use the spatstat package in R to do this. I found a post stating the following code can do this:

```
library(spatstat)
## create example data
dd <- dilation(redwood, 0.5, polygonal=FALSE)
## find connected components
P <- connected(dd)
## convert to a tessellation
B <- tess(image=P)
## compute area of each tile
answer <- tile.areas(B)
```

An owin object (redwood in the above instance) is needed to execute the dilation command and I cannot find a way to convert a raster into an owin object without the maptools package, which is no longer available on CRAN. I also have been unable to install an archived version maptools using devtools.

What would a workaround be for this?

Is there another way to convert a raster into a useable object?

Is there an equally straightforward method for calculating the areas of the fungal 'islands' in my raster image?

Many thanks!

Emily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With "terra" you can first identify the patches, and then count the number of cells in each patch. You could then multiply that number with the actual size of each pixel to get areas. "patches" are defined as islands of values in a sea of missing values; so in this case 255 needs to be set as the missing values flag.

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjIVG.png")
NAflag(x) <- 255
p <- patches(x)
f <- freq(p)
f
#  layer value count
#1     1     1 36015
#2     1     2 17132
#3     1     3 15571
#4     1     4 15345
#5     1     5 38977
#6     1     6 48821
#7     1     7 49660
#8     1     8 41246
```

Some illustration

```
bnds <- as.polygons(p)
area <- subst(p, f$value, f$count)

plot(trim(p, 100), main="ID")
plot(trim(area, 100), main="area")
lines(bnds, col="dark gray")
text(bnds, cex=.75)
```

[image]

To go from pixel counts to area you need to know the size of your image in the real world. Let's say it has a height of 20 and a width of 15 cm. In that case you could do

```
ext(x) <- c(0, 15, 0, 20)
cell_size <- prod(res(x))

f$area <- f$count * cell_size
head(f)
#  layer value count     area
#1     1     1 36015 0.900375
#2     1     2 17132 0.428300
#3     1     3 15571 0.389275
#4     1     4 15345 0.383625
#5     1     5 38977 0.974425
#6     1     6 48821 1.220525
```

With area expressed in cm<sup>2</sup>.

At that point you could also go the polygons-route suggested by Eduardo like this:

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjIVG.png")
NAflag(x) <- 255
ext(x) <- c(0, 15, 0, 20)
crs(x) <- "local"

a <- as.polygons(x)  |> disagg()
a$id <- 1:nrow(a)
a$area <- expanse(a, transform=FALSE)


plot(a, "area")
text(a)

head(data.frame(a))
#  XjIVG id     area
#1     0  1 0.900375
#2     0  2 0.428300
#3     0  3 0.389275
#4     0  4 0.383625
#5     0  5 0.974425
#6     0  6 1.220525
```

PS: Note that if this were geographic data you would want to set the coordinate reference system with `crs<-` and use `cellSize` to get the actual size of the cells in the real world and then use `zonal` to compute the area of each patch.

Comment: This is a really great way to go about it! I especially like that the fungal 'islands' are numbered. I think this is the best answer, but I've upvoted all the answers that offered useful solutions. If I could upvote this twice, I would!

Comment: If you think this is the best answer you can  ✔  "accept" it.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out  what the cell size is in order to calculate the actual size of the islands. Is it possible to do given an image of known dimensions? Would I divide the x and y scale values in the plot by the actual dimensions of the image?

Also, do you know what the 'value' column designates? I've tried this with a different image and it doesn't correspond to the patch for some reason. For example, patch 2 will have a value of 5 and so on.

And I've accepted the answer. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I have added the area computations to my answer. "value" always refers to the patch number. You would need to inspect inspect `p` to see how the patches are numbered.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest a different approach. Instead of 'spatstat', consider using the 'terra' package to read the raster and vectorise it, with the functions 'rast', and as 'as.polygons'. Then you can convert to an 'sf' object, with the function 'st_as_sf', and use the function 'st_cast', which will convert the multipart polygon into multiple singlepart polygons. Finally, you can use the function 'st_area' to calculate the area of all "islands". Please see the example code below.

```
library(terra)
library(sf)

# Read the raster into a SpatRaster object
raster_i <- rast("XjIVG.png")

# Chek the raster resolution
# It by defaut shoud be 1x1
res(raster_i)

# Polygonyze the raster
poly_i <- as.polygons(raster_i, aggregate=T)

# Separate the polygons into individual features
poly_i <- st_cast(st_as_sf(poly_i[1]), "POLYGON")

# Calculate the features area
# Since the resolution is 1x1 the area will be in pixel squared. 
# You can multiply by your scale factor squared to convert the pixel squared units to metric units.
poly_i$area <- st_area(poly_i)

# write the area values of all "islands" in a .csv table
write.csv(data.frame(poly_i)[,c(1,3)], "poly_i.csv")

# Plot the features with a color scale by area
plot(poly_i["area"])
```

The result of this code will be a 'sf' vector object with the islands' area in pixel-squared units. To convert to your measurement units, you can multiply these values by your scale factor squared. See the results plotted with a colour scale by the "islands" area:
[image]

If this was helpful, please remember to recommend the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need `maptools` since your data is in png format.
The following modification of the `spatstat` workflow should work
(`png` package must be installed):

```r
library(spatstat)
# Read in png as a matrix:
mat_png <- png::readPNG("XjIVG.png")
# There are different conventions of how a matrix should be layed out to 
# represent points in a Cartesian coordinate system, so a conversion is needed:
mat_im <- transmat(mat_png, from = "European", to = "spatstat")
i <- as.im(mat_im)
# White pixels are 1 and black 0, so 1 should be treated as background:
cc <- connected.im(i, background = 1)
B <- tess(image=cc)
answer <- tile.areas(B)
# Areas of the components in number of pixels (multiply by pixel area to get
# physical area):
answer
#>     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
#> 41246 49660 48821 38977 15345 15571 36015 17132
# Visual confirmation of components:
plot(B)
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastically simple. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can still download and install the `{maptools}` package from the CRAN archive.

```
> install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/maptools/maptools_1.1-8.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
> library(maptools)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping with the first part of the problem. I was able to install and load maptools thanks to your comment, but when I convert the raster to a pixel image object and then an owin object, the owin object is just a black mask. I need for the owin object or ppp to capture the islands and am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You said you needed the maptools pkg and implied you had a strategy in mind. Now you say that is not the case. Generally comments that ask “what have you tried” get deleted as rude or insulting, but perhaps you should indicate what resources you were consulting and the code that you have deployed in this effort and the full error messages or a complete description of the unsatisfactory results.

Comment: Thanks for following up! I had thought converting the raster into a pixel image (im) and then into an owin object would create a mask image that would consist of the fungal 'islands' in the raster, but it doesn't appear to. I need to capture the extent of those islands and then calculate the area of each individual island. My understanding was that the strategy I stated above would work, but also hoped that someone might chime in if they has a better suggestion for getting the end result I'm looking for. The individual areas of each individual island in the raster.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `{mmand}` package.

```r
IMG <- "XjIVG.png"

library(png)
library(mmand)

image <- readPNG(IMG)

display(image)

kernel <- shapeKernel(c(10, 10), type="box")

erode(image, kernel)

dilate(image, kernel)
```

The eroded image:

[image: The eroded image.]

The dilated image:

[image: The dilated image.]

The operations are being applied to the *white* areas of the image. If you want to erode/dilate the black bits then you need to either negate the image or just use the "other" operation (dilation on black is like erosion on white).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `{spatstat}` then try this.
I couldn't get it to work with `owin` but a point pattern seemed feasible.

```r
IMG <- "XjIVG-smaller.png"

library(spatstat)
library(png)

image <- readPNG(IMG)

coords <- which(image == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
coords <- as.data.frame(coords)
points <- ppp(coords$row, coords$col, window=owin(range(coords$row), range(coords$col)))

radius <- 5
dilated_points <- dilation(points, radius)

plot(dilated_points)
```